# Get Nth item from SelectList

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, ienumerable, selectlist, selectlistitem

I'm trying to unit test a function which returns a SelectList.

How can I retrieve an item from the SelectList to verify that my model is being constructed correctly?

`mySelectList.Items.First().DataValue`

or whatever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply use `mySelectList.ElementAt(n)` to get the nth SelectListItem.